Residue calulations
I am trying to calculate the residue of
\begin{equation*}
f(z)=\frac{ze^{iz}}{z^4+1}
\end{equation*}
at $z=e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}}$. I calculate it as:
\begin{equation*}
Res_{z=e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}}}=\frac{e^{i}\frac{\pi}{4}e^{ie^{i\frac{\pi}{4}}}}{(e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}}-e^{i\frac{3}{4}\pi})(e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}}-e^{i\frac{5}{4}\pi})(e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}}-e^{i\frac{7}{4}\pi})}
\end{equation*}
since $z^4+1=(z-e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}})(z-e^{i\frac{3}{4}\pi})(z-e^{i\frac{5}{4}\pi})(z-e^{i\frac{7}{4}\pi})$.
What I obtain is:
\begin{equation*}
Res_{z=e^{I\frac{\pi}{4}}}=-\frac{1}{4\sqrt{2}}(1+i)\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+i\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)e^{-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}\left(\cos\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)+i\sin\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\right)
\end{equation*}
Do you think it is correct or wrong?

It is correct, but you shouldn't calculate this way.

And what is the best way to calculate it?

Hint: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_(complex_analysis)#Simple_poles
